# Fatal error: Unknown: Timezone database is corrupt - this should *never* happen! in Unknown on line 0

Tags: php, mysql, nginx, frameworks, phalcon

Fatal error: include(): Timezone database is corrupt - this should *never* happen! in /var/www/dresscode2/app/Providers/Database.php on line 5 in nginx and mariadb with pahalcon 3.3

Comment: That is not a question.

Comment: i am using phalcon demo project with nginx server and also using mariadb; in the pdo when i trying to use db connnection using  time zone america/toronto. this error is showing sir